# Render editable UI based on flow + slow updates in editable views that overroll each other

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I wonder how I can solve following problem with a good design.

**Problem**

- the UI renders its state based on a flow
- the user can edit the state and this edit must be persisted
- the user can make consecutive updates quite fast, persisting may need some time (and so will the reemission of the new state)

This can lead to the case that the user edits and edits and is not seeing the new state yet (if the flow is the only source for the view).

**Question**

How can I solve that issue?

**Constructed Code Example**

The user can edit the state via buttons (increase/decrease a value) and persisting needs something between 100 and 1000ms. But the user is able to click the button faster than the persisting and this leads to problems. What's a good design to solve this?

*Example Fragment*

```kotlin
class FlowUIFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFlowUiBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentFlowUiBinding.inflate(inflater)

        // Init UI (Listeners)
        initUI()

        // Observe Data
        observeData()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initUI() {
        // Clicking a button increase/decreases the number
        // this will lead to a reemission of the new value to the flow
        val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { button ->
            val modifier = if (button == binding.btIncrease) 1 else -1
            val value = binding.tvValue.text.toString().toInt()
            GlobalScope.launch {
                updateData(value + modifier)
            }
        }
        listOf(
            binding.btIncrease,
            binding.btDecrease
        ).forEach {
            it.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
        }
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        // we want to use a flow because in a real application there may be cases where updates come
        // from somewhere else, from "outside" and we want this UI to react to it...
        // this simple example would work with a simply suspend function for the initial value as well
        // but we want to find out how to solve this specific problem
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                DemoDataStore.flow
                    .collect {
                        binding.tvValue.text = it.toString()
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateData(value: Int) {
        // this update will need between 100 and 1000ms,
        // this means, the user may be faster increasing/decreasing the value
        // than the update will finish and will emit a new value to the flow above
        // => Problems: overwriting current user value with an old value that's already outdated and as a result, this outdated
        // value may be used to calculate the next state on the next button click...
        DemoDataStore.update(
            value,
            delayInMillis = Random.nextLong(100, 1000)
        )
    }
}
```

*Example DataStore*

```kotlin
object DemoDataStore {

    private val stateFlow: MutableStateFlow<Int> = MutableStateFlow(0)

    val flow: Flow<Int> = stateFlow

    suspend fun update(value: Int, delayInMillis: Long = 1000) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(delayInMillis)
            stateFlow.emit(value)
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 1 - NOT DESIRED**

Locking the UI, showing a progress bar somewhere and wait for the next state after each click is not the solution I'd like to have here, because it makes sense to allow the user to click the button multiple times as fast as he can.

**Solution 2 - NOT DESIRED**

I need to track the state locally as well and switch to loading the initial value only. But in this case I may be missing an update that theoretically may come from outside, from somewhere else...

I really would like to use a `Flow` in this scenario, but I can't think of a good design in this use case and would appreciate any ideas to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener for broadcasting from the server.
There exists a [broadcast coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/broadcast.html) but that was replaced by [shareIn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) since version 1.5.0.
The approach is to get always the updated values from the server and if they differ with the client's values can update those additionally to the updates based on the user input.
Another approach would be to request the current values by a simple AJAX request, that would slow down the process as the request would be sent regularly in short intervals while broadcasting could be done only if it's required.
The weak point is a situation with network problems occur and the broadcasting isn't reaching the clients or only partially. But network problems might always be a challenge and you've to consider them in any case.
This solution is solving the problem you mentioned that several clients might alter the values.

Concerning the persistence you've to transfer clicks on a stack and persist the stack then within short intervals. Like this the client's can click faster than the persisting process takes and each  persisting process starts only after the last one has finished.
This leads obviously to the situation that the values on the server and the broadcast-process might not be 100% accurate in real time when many clicks from several clients are done but in the end the values should be correct as long as no network problems occur.
Certainly further problems like a slow or hanging client device can occur too, but I think there is probably a limit which kind of problems you can recognize, catch and handle.
It's also possible to make the persistence asynchronous, especially if the answer from the server takes longer time, but depending on your detailed solution it might get unreliable or at least more complicated.